# How to remove OOTB attributes from Backoffice

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I need to remove Out of the box attributes from Backoffice, these attributes are defined in the multipe OOTB extensions.

Comment: They are defined as  : <editorArea:section name="hmc.section.product.untypedfeatures">
     <editorArea:attribute description="hmc.text.product.untypedfeatures" qualifier="untypedFeatures"/>
    </editorArea:section>

Comment: maybe you need to figure out what OOTB extensions your project really needs and remove the others. This way you will get rid of unwanted and unused attributes.

Comment: I have figured out, I need to know what approach I can use to remove those attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if you want to hide these attributes from backoffice or you want these attributes to be removed completely from the database.

**If you just want to hide them,** you can add the following custom property for these attributes in the items.xml:

```
<custom-properties>
  <property name="hiddenForUI">
      <value>Boolean.TRUE</value>
  </property>
</custom-properties>
```

Please check `core-items.xml` for some examples.

Alternatively, you can import the following ImpEx:

```
INSERT_UPDATE AttributeDescriptor;qualifier[unique=true];enclosingType(code)[unique=true];hiddenForUI 
;the-attribute-to-be-hidden;the-itemtype-to-which-the-attribute-belongs;TRUE
```

**If you want them to be removed completely from the database**, you can do the following things:

1. Identify the extensions in which they have been defined and if any of these extensions are not required, just remove them from `localextensions.xml`
2. Remove these attributes from their respective items.xml

Then, you need to execute `ant clean all updatesystem`. However, the columns corresponding to these attributes will still persist in the database as system update does not remove/drop any table/column from the database (you can only add new tables/columns and add/update/remove the **data** using system update). In most of the cases, system initialization is also not a possibility. So, you are left with only one option, which is to delete the columns from the database using the SQL queries.